# SSRS -- possible to check if the User!UserID is in a network group from a dataset query?

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I was wondering if there is a was to check if the "Current User" (User!UserID) running the report is in a network group, from the dataset query of a report?  Currently we are restricting access to data based on the "CurrentUser" by checking in the where clause of a SQL query, for example, if the CurrentUser is the "Creator" of a domain object.  Based on this, if the CurrentUser is not the creator, then no data will be returned in the result set to the report.  Now I want to add another condition in the where clause, which is, to check if the User!UserId is in a network group.  Is this possible?  If not, can anyone give any suggestions on whether I should be trying to accomplish this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. You can add an Active Directory server as a linked server and then use openquery() to execute requests.

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5259887.html